# Not able to send Partner Users "Thanks Badge " - new Chatter Feature

Tags: chatter, partner-communities, partner

1. I am trying to send to "thanks badge" to a Partner Community member, but when I type the Partner User name in the 'Name of the person to send' It doesn't able to search the Partner User.
2. Also When I logged-in as Partner User, I am not able to see the 'Thanks' option in the Chatter.

How can this be achieved ??

Comment: When you're doing #1, are you doing this logged in as a SF User and searching Contacts with a Partner User Filter or how are you doing your search? A lot of this will greatly depend on how your org is set up to identify Partners in contacts since they're likely not "Users" in the SF context. In communities, its difficult to say what permissions you've granted/configured in terms of searching for other contacts and Partner Users. Look in your Partner Profile to see what's allowed for each object.

Comment: Q1 - yes I am logged in as SF Full User & Just typing the name of Partner User in section 'to whom THANKS badge to send'.</br>
a. What do you mean by 'Partner User filter' ?
b. How can I check this 'how your org is set up to identify Partners in contacts' ?

Comment: Are you in your Partner Portal inside SF when doing this search or are you using SF's Contacts Tab? Contacts may be set up with different kinds of filters like "contacts I own", "All Contacts", etc. Same situation could occur with your Partner Lookup. Are you an Admin or a User? You may not have the needed Permissions to see them or the access to them may not be enabled in your portal. You'll need to check your configuration to find out.

Comment: I believe you are getting my question in wrong direction,
1. There is a feature introduced with Chatter Post to send 'Thanks Badge' to the users as per the requirement. (I am not using any object here like Contact as you mentioned). Also I am doing this in my PROD org & not in Communities [we are not using any partner portals]
2. I am system administrator in my org therefore I guess I have all the permission to see & setup Partner Users.

Link on which you can find the Chatter Thanks feature details: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_chatter_thanks.htm

Comment: Yup! Totally missed where you were coming from. I recommend you edit your original post to convey that to those who might read it. I can't help you with your problem, but someone else who reads it in the correct context might be able to.